# How do I set a QDate to the current date?

Tags: c++, qt4

I have a `Registration` class that includes a `QDate` member. How do I initialize it to the current date?

```
#include <QDate>

class Registration {
private:
  Person m_Attendee;
  QDate m_BookingDate; // how do I initialze this?
public:
  Registration(Person a);
};

Registration::Registration(Person a): m_Attendee(a) {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html, you can use `QDateTime::currentDateTime()` to get the date.

Comment: so in registration.cpp shall I put const QDate Registration::BookingDate= currentDateTime();

Comment: `Registration::Registration(Person a): m_Attendee(a), m_BookingDate(QDate::currentDate()) {}`

Comment: Yes, this is the constructor definition.